# How can we discover a service in Eureka using a qualifying property with Spring Cloud and Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-feign

We have about 50 microservices developed using Spring Boot. We use Spring Cloud for registering services with Eureka and invoke the service from the consumer using Feign. The contract is pretty standard, where the consumer uses an interface with `@FeignClient("<foo>")` annotation to locate a service that's registered as `foo` with Eureka. The registration, lookup and invocation on the target service all works as expected with one or multiple instances of the service running.

We have a new requirement where the same service `foo` may be running multiple instances where each instance has a specific *stereotype* or *designation*. For example, some instances of `foo` are expected to deal with 3rd party integration synchronous workload, and some instances of `foo` are expected to deal with internal messages (asynchronous workload). We have defined a configuration property called `stereotype` in the service that would be defined at the bootstrap (done via part of Spring Cloud config) to tell the service instance to deal with `sync` or `async` workloads. The configuration looks like this:

```
service.stereotype: sync # or async
```

In addition, we also add this property to the Eureka's `eureka.instance.metadatamap` map as `stereotype` property when registering the service `foo`. I can see that the Eureka now displays this value for service `foo` when it gets registered.

So far so good. Now the question:

Is there a configuration (or annotation) mechanism in either the `DiscoveryClient` or Feign to lookup `foo` but using the `stereotype` as a qualifier. In other words, when my consumer application looks up Eureka, can it somehow tell Eureka to give only the instance where, for example, the `stereotype` is `async`? If this is possible, then my consumer component can ensure that the asynchronous workload is only sent to the `foo` instance that deals with asynchronous workload.

So far, in my research, I have not found anything. I wrote a sample (that can possibly go in a `DiscoveryClient` override) that would use Eureka REST interface `GET /eureka/v2/apps/appID` as outlined [here](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Eureka-REST-operations) and then find the target endpoint by looking up the metadata map for each instance that's returned. But that sounded like brute force. I'd ideally like to do this using one of the existing mechanisms if available, so that I can continue using the load balancing and retry features of Feign instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Trying to approach it a different way... Why not register the service that deals with sync or async as two disparate service names in Eureka? Setup your application so that the `spring.application.name` is `foo-sync` or `foo-async`. Then the Feign client would just use that specific name to get the right instances?

Comment: That was the first thing that came to mind, but it doesn't work as the idea is not to have to hardcode the `stereotype` in the Feign client. That information is more environment specific and not something that's readily available at the time of development. It can definitely do what we need technically, but if there's a way to do it through environment specific configuration, that'd be ideal.